# Django creating duplicate follow relationships -- concurrency issues suspected when creating new data in table

Tags: python, mysql, django, concurrency

Let me explain my particular situation:

A business can pick a neighbourhood they are in, this option is persisted to the DB, a signal is fired when this objects is saved. A method listens for this signal and should only once update all other users who follow this neighbourhood as well. There is a check that happens in this method, trying to verify if any other user is already following this business, for every user that is not following this business, but following this neighbourhood, a follow relation will be created in the db. Everything should be fine, if user is already following this business, then no relation is set...

But what happes is that sometimes two or more of these transactions happen at the same time, all of them checking if the user is following this business, of course, since none of them can see a follow relation between the user and the business, multiple follow relations are now established.

I tried making sure the signal isn't sent multiple times, but I'm not sure why these multiple transactions are happening at the same time.

While I have found some answers to doing row locking when trying to avoid concurrency problems on updates, I am at a loss about how to make sure that only one insert happens.

Is table locking the only way to ensure that one one insert of a kind happens?

```
# when a business updates their neighborhood, this sets the follow relationship

def follow_biz(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if instance.neighborhood:
        neighborhood_followers = FollowNeighborhood.objects.filter(neighborhood=instance.neighborhood)
        # print 'INSTANCE Neighborhood %s ' % instance.neighborhood
        for follower in neighborhood_followers:

            if not Follow.objects.filter(user=follower.user, business=instance).count():
                follow = Follow(business=instance, user=follower.user)
                follow.save()

# a unique static string to prevent signal from being called twice
follow_biz_signal_uid = hashlib.sha224("follow_biz").hexdigest()

# signal
post_save.connect(follow_biz, sender=Business, dispatch_uid=follow_biz_signal_uid)
```

Comment: I'm looking at this snippet, http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/833/#c4232

Comment: Final answer is doing a unique constraint on (user_id,business_id)

Comment: I tried to improve the answer using your findings and tried to kept it as general for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By ensuring uniqueness[1] of the rows at the database level using a constraint on the relevant columns Django, AFAICT, will do the right thing and insert or update as necessary.

In this case the constraint should be on the user and business id.

[1] Of course ensuring uniqueness where applicable is always a good idea.

Comment: Cannot use unqueness constraint, I should have made that clear, because the same business can be followed many times, and the same user can follow multiple businesses... they just shouldn't follow the same business multiple times.